# jquery returns true to event handler but the event (get input) will not be ended

Tags: jquery, html, input, event-handling

I have a form which contains input radio elements (2nd level under the header) into headers (to generate a selection) - this have been tested and functions normally.

To manage headers I have a query event click which performs (verified) actions when the header is not in the described case. So if we are not into the cases the .click event simple returns true to go on just after the test (a simple if).

The problem is that the input is not performed (the radio button which is into the header is never checked).

Note : If the actions are performed (no test done) the actions are performed and a second click is needed from user to get the radio button to be checked. This is the lonely case that I could check the radio button.

The js code is (summarized) :

```
$(".H_title")
        .focusin(function(event) {
            if ( ... )  { do stuff }
            return true; // go on action
          } )
        .focusout(function() {...do_stuff);} );
//END
```

What can be the reason ?

Note : I cannot change quite anything into the html structure on which I operate because it is generated by several codes (php and other js). I must be able to check the radio buttons into the page without changing the structure and contents.

Best regards

Trebly

Comment: Hard to understand what the issue is here. You mention click event but show code for focusing a class we have no idea what it is. Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces your issue and a better explanation of the actual problem

Comment: JQuery running is 1.12.4

Comment: Checked at the end when jquery-migrate (1.4.1) is reached in "jQuery.event.trigger" that "event" has "bubbles = false".. Others data of the event and linked elements found into object in debugger are OK.

Comment: The issue is that nothing happens.

Comment: Nothing happens to what? Without an actual example your question is very hard to comprehend and is confusing

Comment: .H_title is a span into which the input is placed. When the user clicks on the header (doesn't see clearly the content) into which the input is (the header is 3 level up while the form is 4th) and on which I makes changes (using "closest header). The event found which is bubbled false is the right input.

Comment: Talking about these elements we can't see is not helping. Show us the html and the other relevant code that reproduces whatever the problem is. Did you even read how to create a  [mcve]

Comment: Nothing happens means that when user clicks on the radio button (or necessarily on the header which contains the button) nothing is performed : the input option is not selected. This while when the click is submitted the "stuff" under the "if" is executed but the "return true" (in both case) do not continue the begun action by the selection of the button which is depending of the "span" clicked. I think that, after some hours spent thinking to something else, with the event triggered the return true bubbles out of the H_title container but the event click on the inside input is not executed

Comment: Less text...more code. Where's the demo?? So much can be learned with a demo using browser developer tools

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to charlietfi for help in this question.

I understand that my explanations were not sufficiently precise to understand the case. More I had introduced an error when copying code.

There is a true problem of which I have found a solution which reaches the target but I am not sure of both the explanation of why it was not functioning and why it functions now.

There where two steps of development :

1- Just execute stuff when a span into a header is clicked (and but not involved another stuff on focusin the element while shiftkey is pressed).
The HTML structure contains :

```
<h5>
   <span class="toc-target" tabindex="1000"> <!-- puts the "target" on top -->
      <span class="H_title">
           Adhérent
      </span>
   </span>
   <span class="endof_tocid"></span>
</h5>
```

The reason of the first two levels of SPAN is that it is done by two different pieces of soft and need two different classes.

The associated code which was functioning (since three years) was :

```
$(".H_title")
        .click(function(event) {
            if ( ... )  { do stuff1 }
            return true; // go on action
          } )
        .focusin(function() {...do_stuff2a);} );
        .focusout(function() {...do_stuff2b);} );
//END
```

2- I need to had in some cases a radio button and do no perform stuff1 in such case (just add an input into the header) then the HTML code became :

```
<h5>
   <span class="toc-target" tabindex="1000"> <!-- puts the "target" on top -->
      <span class="H_title">
         <input name="user_type" type="radio" value="adh">
           Adhérent
      </span>
   </span>
   <span class="endof_tocid"></span>
</h5>
```

and I wrote the js code which do not functions:

```
$(".H_title")
        .click(function(event) {
            if ( ... )  { do stuff1 }
            return true; // go on action of the click on the button
          } )
        .focusin(function() {...do_stuff2a);} );
        .focusout(function() {...do_stuff2b);} );
//END
```

In my opinion the error seems that the radio button become not reachable into the H_title span while it is without code to manage the event. Note : this is the same for focusin actions and events.

**If there is no Jquery code written for the click event everything is running normally.**

```
//BEGIN    
$(".toc-target > input")
      .click( function(){ return true; }); 
      .focusin(function() {return true; } );
      .focusout(function() {return true; } );
$(".H_title")
        .click(function(event) {
            if ( ... )  { do stuff1: move-top }
            return true; // go on actions
          } )
        .focusin(function() {...do_stuff2a);} );
        .focusout(function() {...do_stuff2b);} );
//END
```

**With this code the click on the input functions, what is the behavior :**
1- the `$(".toc-target > input")` events are raised and return true which seems to do nothing lead to the normal selection of the radio button and event bubbles.
2- the H_titles gets his click event and it is executed it normally.

For now the focusin-focusout doesn't still function combined with the buttons I think that the problem comes from a conflict with the click (the fact that the header gets focus when clicked).
I have to clarify some ones about full ergonomics points and about compatibility (available on PC and Mobiles).

**Another solution could be it seems "propagation" from H_title to the "input"** but I have not found a good way to do everything needed into stuffxx and separate clearly the actions.

May be I am wrong or may be you have some suggestions to do it in a best way.

Best regards

Trebly